# DragulaJs - Drag from a specific button only

Tags: javascript, dragula

I have a div that has several cards inside them, I want to use dragula to allow setting the order of the cards by drag and drop. However I only want to allow dragging from a specific button only.

I tried setting the button as the container but that only moves the button. If I set the card as the container, the whole card is draggable from anywhere.

HTML

```
<div id="container">
    <div class="card">
        <figure>
            <a href="scent/giorgio-armani-acqua-di-gio"><img src="img/perfumes/armani-acqua-di-gio.jpg"></a>
            <button type="button" class="btn icon drag-handle"><span class="material-icons">drag_indicator</span></button>
        </figure>
        <div class="content">
            <p>Acqua Di Gio</p>
            <button type="button" class="btn text remove-slot">Remove</button>
        </div>
    </div>
    ...
    ...
</div>
```

JS

```
const dragulaV = dragula({
  revertOnSpill: true
});
document.querySelectorAll('#container .drag-handle').forEach(el => {
    dragulaV.containers.push(el);
});
```

[image: screenshot]

**To summarize**: I want to move `.card` and I only want to trigger it with `.drag-handle`.